# Why is $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$ the universal example of a holomorphic function that fails to have a primitive?

Tags: complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, laurent-series

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) (on Morera's theorem) mentions the following in the introduction.

> In a certain sense, the $\frac{1}{z}$ counterexample is universal: for every analytic function that has no antiderivative on its domain, the reason for this is that $\frac{1}{z}$ itself does not have an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Why is this statement true? In particular, what is the connection between the failure of an arbitrary holomorphic function to have a primitive and the failure of $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$ to have a primitive? Perhaps this is related to term-wise integration of Laurent series?

Comment: yes pretty much. Every holomorphic function on an annulus has a Laurent expansion. We know that for any $n\neq -1$, $z^n$ has $\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$ as antiderivative. If $\frac{1}{z}$ also had an anti-derivative in an annulus centered at the origin, then every term in the Laurent expansion has antiderivatives, and hence so does the whole series (term-by-term manipulation is always valid as long as we're within the annulus of convergence). Unfortunately, $\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have an antiderivative in an annulus (centered at origin), so that's the one and only troublesome term.

Comment: @peek-a-boo So then is it true that every holomorphic function that fails to have a primitive has a nonzero residue (i.e. the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion is nonzero)? Otherwise, a primitive can be found by term-wise antidifferentiation, correct?

Comment: yes (assuming of course that we're looking at the annulus centered at the origin; otherwise you need to look at the residue about a different point).